# Import C#.NET Code Coverage to SonarQube 5.1.2 using Visual Studio Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube5.1

I'm having a issue import .NET Coverage to SonarQube 5.1.2 using Visual Studio Code Coverage when following instructions on http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770. I use sample Sonar project from Git. Here's my .bat file:

`MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"UTTestCSharp" /n:"UTTestCSharp" /v:"1.0" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="MyDir/VisualStudio.coveragexml"
msbuild /t:rebuild
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Dynamic Code Coverage Tools/CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"MyDir/VisualStudio.coverage"
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/vstest.console.exe" "UnitTestProject1/bin/Debug/UnitTestProject1.dll"
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Dynamic Code Coverage Tools/CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:"MyDir/VisualStudio.coveragexml" "MyDir/VisualStudio.coverage"
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end`

The process just stop at the part generating `VisualStudio.coverage`, like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7S7G.png).
If I re-run the bat file then the process just skips the generating part and finishes success, but there's  no Coverage report on Sonar Server. I need to see Code Coverage report on the Sonar Dashboard. Please help.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to upgrade to SonarQube 5.6 LTS and also update your plugins and runner to the latest version.

Comment: Thank @JeroenHeier for your suggestion, but for some reasons I'm not allowed to do that to Sonar Server at my firm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command line. I found typos in SonarQube [doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770) page. (For VS2015)

```
"C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.1.554\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /v:1.0 /k:UTTestCSharp /n:UTTestCSharp
"C:\SonarQube\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.3.1.554\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /v:1.0 /k:UTTestCSharp /n:UTTestCSharp /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=".\VisualStudio.coveragexml"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -p:Configuration=Release
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:".\VisualStudio.coverage" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /EnableCodeCoverage ".\bin\Release\UTTestCSharp.dll"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" analyze /output:".\VisualStudio.coveragexml" ".\VisualStudio.coverage"
```

Also add the "Generic Coverage" plugin. It has something to do with coverage report.